# Automator Rsync Error

Tags: macos, backup, rsync, automator

I'm trying to troubleshoot an error in a simple worklfow that I made.
The purpose is rsync a NAS ethernet storage to an Internal RAID on a MacPro.

It goes like this:

- Get specified text
- Speak text
- New Folder
  (called NAS_ on a internal RAID of my MacPro)
- Run Shell Script (as arguments)
  (rsync -ravx -h --progress /Volumes/shared1 /Volumes/OFFICE_BKP/NAS_BKP/NAS_)
- Get specified Finder Items
  (NAS_)
- Rename finder Items: Add Date or Time
  (NAS_ to NAS_currentdate)

When I run the script on different folder, smaller in size than the 1GB NAS, it works fine. So I don't know if there's any problem in my script or a bug somewhere.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the error is.

Comment: Run shell script failed - 1 error
nothing more in the log window